# Android - Printing PDF file with added printer

Tags: android, android-print-manager

I have a PDF file and I want to print it directly to the printer that is connected to my phone.

If I using the code below:

```
val printManager = context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
printManager.print(jobName, printDocumentAdapter, null)
```

It display a preview screen by system. I want to print directly.

How to do that? Please give me some solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk to your printer manufacturer and ask them what sort of direct-print Android SDK they might offer.

Comment: oh, so Are there no way to print directly?

Comment: We have no way of answering that. Only your printer manufacturer can answer that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not aiming to print with a specific printer. I am looking for a solution to print through printers with the same wifi connection.

Comment: "I'm not aiming to print with a specific printer" -- we have needed [printer drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_driver) for the past 30 years on major operating systems, because different printers use different protocols for how we tell them what to print. Android handles that via print services, but that is tied into the `PrintManager` API that you seem to not want to use, and not all printers will have print services available for Android anyway.

Comment: The problem I need to solve is to get a list of printers in the same wifi network. Then, choose to get a printer's information and send the file to that printer for direct printing. Thus, there will be no need to go through the Preview screen and simplify the operations for users.

Comment: That does not change the fact that different printers use different protocols for how you tell it what to print.

Comment: I understood. Thank for your answer.

Comment: Hello @PhongBM, did you figure out how to do so? This is exactly what I am trying to achieve as well..